# MVC3 out of the box membership provider (log on) not working on newly published server?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just published my mvc3 application that uses the default membership provider to login but it seems that the call to anything "Membership" (Membership.ValidateUser-in this case) is causing the following error on the remote server hosting my web application.

Server is 2003 SP2 IIS6.0...my mvc3 application hits sql server 2008 instance.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server.     The server was not found
>   or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
>   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider:
>   SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> SQLExpress database file auto-creation error:

How is the out of the out of the box (new mvc3 app) user/login managed with MVC3 and how can I set this user store up on my remote IIS server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default it creates a connection to a local SQL Express db in your App_Data folder the first time you run the mvc web app and register a user. You will then notice the aspnetdb file is created.

If you wish to use your existing db you need to create the Membership schema on an existing database.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Easiest way is to update the web.config connection string to point to new db and run the install scripts agaist this.

These scripts are located in the WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\ folder with names like InstallCommon.sql, InstallMembership.sql, InstallRoles.sql, InstallProfile.sql, InstallSqlState.sql, and so on.

See this more in depth article for full overview

http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

Comment: Cool, got it working as ported to sql server 2008 instance. Thanks!